# Pedir permiso la primera vez que intento hacer la llamada (Android 6+)

Tags: java, android, permisos

Cuando pulso en la ImageButton por primera vez para que realice la función de hacer la llamada, no hace nada, tengo que ir a ajustes/aplicaciones/... y activar manualmente el permiso de llamada.
Como podría hacer para que me pida el permiso la primera vez que hago la acción?

Tengo el permiso dado en Manisfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package prueba.otrointento;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static prueba.otrointento.R.drawable.icon_des1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;
    ImageButton btn3;
    ImageButton btn4;
    ImageButton btn5;
    ImageButton icon_des1;
    ImageButton icon_des2;
    ImageButton icon_des3;
    ImageButton icon_des4;
    ImageButton icon_des5;
    ImageButton icon_des6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.text_des);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        icon_des1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des1);
        icon_des2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des2);
        icon_des3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des3);
        icon_des4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des4);
        icon_des5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des5);
        icon_des6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des6);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(boton1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton5);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent icon_des4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity_gmail.class);
                startActivity(icon_des4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0000000"));
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    return;
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent icon_des6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity_gmail.class);
                startActivity(icon_des6);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

He estado mirando por la página otras preguntas sobre este tema, pero no lo he conseguido hacer que me pida los permisos.

Gracias!

EDITO:

mainactivity.java - @Naos

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageButton btn1;
ImageButton btn2;
ImageButton btn3;
ImageButton btn4;
ImageButton btn5;
ImageButton icon_des1;
ImageButton icon_des2;
ImageButton icon_des3;
ImageButton icon_des4;
ImageButton icon_des5;
ImageButton icon_des6;

final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 10;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // PERMISO CONCEDIDO, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
            } else {
                // PERMISO DENEGADO
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.text_des);

    btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    icon_des1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des1);
    icon_des2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des2);
    icon_des3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des3);
    icon_des4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des4);
    icon_des5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des5);
    icon_des6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des6);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(boton1);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(boton2);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent boton3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(boton3);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent boton4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class);
            startActivity(boton4);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent boton5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main5Activity.class);
            startActivity(boton5);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    icon_des1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    icon_des2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    icon_des3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    icon_des4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent icon_des4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity_gmail.class);
            startActivity(icon_des4);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });

    icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                // Aquí ya está concedido, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
            }else{
                // Aquí lanzamos un dialog para que el usuario confirme si permite o no el realizar llamadas
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
            }
        }
    });

    icon_des6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent icon_des6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity_gmail.class);
            startActivity(icon_des6);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Por cada llamada queres que te salga un mensaje de permisos al intentar hacer la llamada. Porque queres hacer eso?? es necesario?

Comment: No, perdón si no me expliqué mal. Lo que quiero hacer es que al intentar hacer la llamada por primera vez me pida el permiso, ya que no me lo pide y no hace nada al pulsar sobre ImageButton, tengo que ir yo a ajustes y darle el permiso @josego

Comment: Podrias mejorar la pregunta porfavor.no te pide los permisos pero funciona la llamada?

Comment: Editado, espero que ahora se entienda mejor! @josego

Comment: probaste en desinstalar la app de tu dispositivo y luego volver a instalar

Comment: Si, pero nada @josego

Comment: @UserNameYo No me es claro que es lo que quieres hacer, quiero saber varias cosas ¿qué permiso deseas pedir y en qué botón en específico?

Comment: Quiero que cuando pulse el botón (icon_des5) la aplicación me pida el permiso para realizar la llamada, ya que no lo hace automáticamente (En versiones 6+ de Android) y tengo que darle yo el permiso desde ajustes) @Naos

Comment: @UserNameYo Revisa mi respuesta!

Comment: @UserNameYo agregué un script el cual puedes agregar al iniciar tu aplicación en onCreate() con esto te requerira los permisos necesarios, para Android 6.0 +  no es solo agregarlo al Manifest.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde la documentación oficial de android en español para solicitar permisos [AQUÍ](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es-419) y según tu último comentario deberías corregir esto en tu código para que pida el permiso si no lo tiene concedido:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Aquí están tus objetos de tipo Button ... solo añade la siguiente variable después de estos

    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 10; // Puedes poner cualquier número, solo es para identificarlo

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        // Aquí ya está concedido, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0000000"));
                    }else{
                        // Aquí lanzamos un dialog para que el usuario confirme si permite o no el realizar llamadas
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    // Y finalmente recibimos la respuesta del usuario en un método de tipo `@Override` así:

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // PERMISO CONCEDIDO, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0000000"));
                } else {
                    // PERMISO DENEGADO
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me podrías decir como colocarlo? Estoy empezando en esto y aún no controlo mucho, me da muchos errores, así que imagino que yo lo pongo mal @Naos

Comment: @UserNameYo claro, he de suponer que el primer trozo de código lo entiendes ya que va dentro de tu `listener` para el botón, el segundo trozo de código lo puedes añadir como un método independiente por fuera del `onCreate()`

Comment: He editado el primer mensaje poniendo como coloco tu codigo, pero me da dos errores "cannot find symbol variable MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST _CALL_PHONE y ...variable thisActivity, podrías decirme que pongo mal? Gracias

Comment: @UserNameYo listo, edité mi respuesta, la variable `thisActivity` la debes cambiar por tu actual `MainActivity.this` (dependiendo obvio de en que actividad te encuentras) y la variable `_CALL_PHONE ` definela por fuera del `onCreate()` luego de del `Class MainActivity ... {}`

Comment: @UserNameYo He terminado de editar mi respuesta, espero que te puedas guiar con la edición que hice ya que puse todo dentro del `MainActivity` para que se entendiese mejor

Comment: He vuelto a editar el primer comentario añadiendo como queda ahora el codigo, ahora (porfin!) me pide el permiso para llamar, lo acepto pero no hace la función de llamar, no hace nada al pulsar el boton.

Comment: Bueno, creo que para ello debes revisar y hacer un debug pasó a pasó con el logcat mirando en donde entra y en donde no tu código, si te ayudé a solucionar el problema principal (pedir permiso) considera marcar mi respuesta como correcta y si quieres vamos al chat para orientarte un poco más :)

Comment: Hecho! Como vamos al chat? te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50357/discussion-between-naos-and-usernameyo).

Comment: Hay que añadir: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
startActivity(i);
para que realice la llamada

Answer (score 0):

Para requerir [permisos](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) para llamada telefónica en Android 6.0 o posterior no se realiza únicamente agregando el permiso dentro del AndroidManifest.xml,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Se tiene que requerir de esta forma mediante [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)), este  es un ejemplo:

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```

---

El script anterior lo puedes integrar para que sea llamado al iniciar tu aplicación, esto en tu Activity que inicia la aplicación dentro de `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }

    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Lo sustituyo por el mio, pero me dice "error: incompatibles types: <anonymous OnClickLinstener> cannot be converted to Context / Activity

Comment: @UserNameYo agregué la forma en como debes agregarlo.

Comment: He agregado al primer comentario como pongo tu código, pero me da errores, lo debo poner mal, mira si sabes que hago mal

Comment: @UserNameYo he editado tu código, prueba!

Comment: He copiado y pegado tal cual, para probar y me da varios errores de nuevo, error: illegal start of expression, ')' expected, not a statement, ';' expected, illegal start of expression... y así una larga cola